# Декодировать данные JSON

Tags: php, json

есть JSON строка, но декодировать у меня пока не получается. Подскажите как правильно подобрать аргументы для json_decode если в переменной лежит информация из этой ссылки: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byc08IJpZRKpTTFlWll4SGpoYnM?key=AIzaSyB722vvOKFqd2dviblll7oKBXtDBqSgaVE

Comment: Вы используете PHP?

Comment: да забыл уточнить, на php

Comment: А в чём проблема? json_decode($json_string, true) вернёт массив, а без второго аргумента объект

Comment: а вы попробуйте декодировать, у меня выходит: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Comment: http://185.185.68.11/temp/test.php

Comment: На эту страницу добавил сам код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все декодирует без вопросов

```
<?php 


// Получаем данные
$str    = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byc08IJpZRKpTTFlWll4SGpoYnM?key=AIzaSyB722vvOKFqd2dviblll7oKBXtDBqSgaVE');
// Декодируем данные
$d = json_decode( $str, true);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($d);
echo '</pre>';
```

Если у Вас ошибка - посмотрите что Вам в $str приходит, возможно у Вас ошибка чтения ссылки.

Comment: точно! спасибо большое